# Gnuplot fitting method

Tags: gnuplot

"Fit" in Gnuplot uses which method (Algorithm) for fitting any curve? How does it calculate the error in fitting parameters?

A rough idea about the method or the algorithm would be enough.

Comment: Just type `help fit` or google gnuplot fit and you will get everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the fit command quite often. GNUPLOT is using the least squares with the the Marquardt-Levenberg-algorithm. All available information are on this link [[fit]](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node82.html). What they said about the error can be found here [[error]](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node85.html).

These are quite robust methods and can not be easily implemented. However, if you want have a look at the code that does the job you can find it on GitHub [[code]](https://github.com/gnuplot/gnuplot/blob/master/src/fit.c), that's the advantage with opensource :-).

Hope that helps.